# Combine two lists created from range with different steps and repeat values for certain number of indexes

Tags: python, python-3.6

1. Setting the count, the first list starts at zero and increments by 20 until count is exhausted.
2. Using the same count, the second list starts at 1 repeats 1 for the first five indexes and then
   increments by 1 at 100. Repeats this cycle until list is exhausted.

`aaa` should increment by 20 starting at 0
`bbb` should increment by 1 for every 5th index starting at 1

Results:

```
aaa00_bbb1
aaa20_bbb1
aaa40_bbb1
aaa60_bbb1
aaa80_bbb1
aaa100_bbb2
aaa120_bbb2
aaa140_bbb2
aaa160_bbb2
aaa180_bbb2
aaa200_bbb3
aaa220_bbb3
aaa240_bbb3
aaa260_bbb3
aaa280_bbb3
aaa300_bbb4
aaa320_bbb4 ...
```

Tried something like this but I don't know how to get list `bbb` working.

```
def my_func_a(cnt):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(0, cnt, 20):
        value = 'aaa' + str(i)
        mylist.append(value)
    return mylist

aaa = my_func_a(500)
# print(aaa)

def my_func_b(cnt):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(0, cnt, 20):
        value = '_bbb' + str(i)
        mylist.append(value)
    return mylist

bbb = my_func_b(500)
# print(bbb)

combined = list(map(''.join, zip(map(str, aaa), bbb)))
print(combined)
```

Output:

```
['aaa0_bbb0', 'aaa20_bbb20', 'aaa40_bbb40', 'aaa60_bbb60', 'aaa80_bbb80', 'aaa100_bbb100', 'aaa120_bbb120', 'aaa140_bbb140', 'aaa160_bbb160', 'aaa180_bbb180', 'aaa200_bbb200', 'aaa220_bbb220', 'aaa240_bbb240', 'aaa260_bbb260', 'aaa280_bbb280', 'aaa300_bbb300', 'aaa320_bbb320', 'aaa340_bbb340', 'aaa360_bbb360', 'aaa380_bbb380', 'aaa400_bbb400', 'aaa420_bbb420', 'aaa440_bbb440', 'aaa460_bbb460', 'aaa480_bbb480']
```

Tried some things with itertools and got closer but still bbb I can't get working.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, cycle

def myfunc(cnt):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(0, cnt+20, 20):
        value = 'aaa' + str(i) + '_'
        mylist.append(value)
    return mylist

inventory_list = myfunc(500)
# print(inventory_list)

inventory = list(zip(inventory_list, chain(repeat(1,5), cycle(range(2, 3)))))
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
[('aaa0_', 1), ('aaa20_', 1), ('aaa40_', 1), ('aaa60_', 1), ('aaa80_', 1), ('aaa100_', 2), ('aaa120_', 2), ('aaa140_', 2), ('aaa160_', 2), ('aaa180_', 2), ('aaa200_', 2), ('aaa220_', 2), ('aaa240_', 2), ('aaa260_', 2), ('aaa280_', 2), ('aaa300_', 2), ('aaa320_', 2), ('aaa340_', 2), ('aaa360_', 2), ('aaa380_', 2), ('aaa400_', 2), ('aaa420_', 2), ('aaa440_', 2), ('aaa460_', 2), ('aaa480_', 2), ('aaa500_', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a generator like so:

#### Code:

```
def by_one_5_times():
    i = 1
    while True:
        for j in range(5):
            yield i
        i += 1
```

Then build your strings like so:

```
for numbers in zip(range(0, 400, 20), by_one_5_times()):
    print('aaa{:02d}_bbb{}'.format(*numbers))
```

#### Results:

```
aaa00_bbb1
aaa20_bbb1
aaa40_bbb1
aaa60_bbb1
aaa80_bbb1
aaa100_bbb2
aaa120_bbb2
aaa140_bbb2
aaa160_bbb2
aaa180_bbb2
aaa200_bbb3
aaa220_bbb3
aaa240_bbb3
aaa260_bbb3
aaa280_bbb3
aaa300_bbb4
aaa320_bbb4
aaa340_bbb4
aaa360_bbb4
aaa380_bbb4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['aaa' + str(i) + '_bbb' + str(j) 
           for i in range(0, 100, 20) for j in range(1, 100) 
           for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
b = 0
a = 0

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(a, a + 5 * 20, 20):
        print("aaa" + str(j) + "_bbb" + str(i))
    a = j

# output

aaa0_bbb0
aaa20_bbb0
aaa40_bbb0
aaa60_bbb0
aaa80_bbb0
aaa80_bbb1
aaa100_bbb1
aaa120_bbb1
aaa140_bbb1
aaa160_bbb1
aaa160_bbb2
aaa180_bbb2
aaa200_bbb2
aaa220_bbb2
aaa240_bbb2
aaa240_bbb3
aaa260_bbb3
aaa280_bbb3
aaa300_bbb3
aaa320_bbb3
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm was given to you:

1. Setting the count, the first list starts at zero and increments by 20 until count is exhausted.
2. Using the same count, the second list starts at 1 repeats 1 for the first five indexes and then increments by 1 at 100. Repeats this cycle until list is exhausted.

---

```
def do_this(cnt):
    i, j = 0, 1

    for x in range(1, cnt + 1):
        yield f"aaa{i}_bbb{j}"

        i += 20
        j += not (i % 100)
```

And then iterate over this:

```
for data in do_this(100):
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `count` and `islice`?

```
from itertools import count, islice

gen = (f'aaa{x}_bbb{y}' for x, y in zip(
  count(0, 20), 
  (x for i in count(1, 1) for x in [i] * 5)
))
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
for example in islice(gen, 0, 20):
  print(example)
```

The output:

```
aaa0_bbb0
aaa20_bbb0
aaa40_bbb0
aaa60_bbb0
aaa80_bbb0
aaa100_bbb1
aaa120_bbb1
aaa140_bbb1
aaa160_bbb1
aaa180_bbb1
aaa200_bbb2
aaa220_bbb2
aaa240_bbb2
aaa260_bbb2
aaa280_bbb2
aaa300_bbb3
aaa320_bbb3
aaa340_bbb3
aaa360_bbb3
aaa380_bbb3
```